# Name resolution for dummy interfaces

Tags: linux, dns, bridge, tun

I've a virtual NIC of type NAT on my Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine which connects it to the internet via host. For some processing, I need to route all incoming and outgoing packets via a program I've to write. For example, assume that I've to drop some packets and don't let them go out of the VM.

For this, I created a dummy interface with the following:

```
modprobe dummy
ip link add tun0 type dummy
ifconfig tun0 up
```

For all traffics not to go directly through the NIC, I added:

```
ip route add default dev tun0
```

Now everything is ok. For example when I

```
ping 4.2.2.4
```

, I see that the ping is not answered when my program is not running and is answered properly when it's running. The program works like a bridge between enp0s3 and tun0 for now. The whole traffic is routing through my program. Just a problem exists, name resolution. That's when I

```
ping google.com
```

, the name can't be resolved. The route table now is as follows:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
```

Of couse if I

```
sudo route del default
```

, the name resolution takes place via the NAT adapter through the host properly. Please let me know what's wrong with the name resolution in this situation.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not linux or networking issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Thanks for the information. How can I move this topic to server fault?